# Database - first: Entity Foreign key property not populated

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I have 2 tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t2 
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY, 
    description VARCHAR (100)
);

CREATE TABLE t1 
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY, 
    t2_id INT, 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_t2] FOREIGN KEY ([t2_id]) REFERENCES t2 (id)
)

INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (1, 'Item 1')
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (2, 'Item 2')
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1, 1)
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (2, 2)
```

Using the `scaffold-dbcontext` command I created the entities:

```sql
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=your_server;Database=your_database;Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=true;" 
         Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 
         -Tables "dbo.t1", "dbo.t2" -ContextDir test 
         -outputDir "test\Entitites" -Context TestCtx -DataAnnotations -NoOnConfiguring
```

Here is the source code for the entities & dbcontext:

```cs
[Table("t1")]
public partial class T1
{
    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("t2_id")]
    public int? T2Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("T2Id")]
    [InverseProperty("T1s")]
    public virtual T2? T2 { get; set; }
}

[Table("t2")]
public partial class T2
{
    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("description")]
    [StringLength(100)]
    [Unicode(false)]
    public string? Description { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("T2")]
    public virtual ICollection<T1> T1s { get; set; } = new List<T1>();
}

public partial class TestCtx : DbContext
{
    public TestCtx(DbContextOptions<TestCtx> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<T1> T1s { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<T2> T2s { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<T1>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Id).HasName("PK__t1__3213E83F15C7958E");

            entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();

            entity.HasOne(d => d.T2).WithMany(p => p.T1s).HasConstraintName("FK_t2");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<T2>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Id).HasName("PK__t2__3213E83F6D179575");

            entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();
        });

        OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
    }

    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
}
```

This code was added to an ASP.NET Core MVC app. When I execute the following code in a controller (this controller was injected the `TestCtx` object) method to view a page:

```csharp
var t1s = testCtx.T1s.ToList();
// var t2s = testCtx.T2s.ToList();
t1s.ForEach(it => Console.WriteLine($"{it.Id} ->{it.T2?.Id}"));
```

it prints out:

```sql
1 ->
2 ->
```

I find this behavior very surprising, in other words, it doesn't pull the references to the T2 entities. I am in process of converting an ASP.NET MVC app to .NET Core and in particular an EF `dbcontext` from EF 6 to EF Core 7 and that's not how EF 6 behaves, as far as I know.

If I pull all the T2 entities in a list before the ForEach call, then it's going to work as expected:

```sql
1 ->1
2 ->2
```

Project file:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="7.0.11">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I am targeting .NET Core 6 but I used EF Core 7. I am not sure if this is frowned upon, but it didn't complain when I added the references.

What is the reasoning for this behavior?

Thanks

Comment: [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/)

Answer (score 0):

After enabling Lazy Loading With proxies, it worked as expected.

I followed these instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy

```
    builder.Services.AddDbContext<TestCtx>(options =>
      options
        .UseLazyLoadingProxies(true)
        .UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("cn")));
```

Regarding my usage in the example,it is inefficient indeed to pull the list, then loop through the items and print a referenced object, but I just wanted to test it. I still find the fact that it didn't work out-of-the-box surprising.